# Can two variables be used in a function at once?

Tags: php

The function `check_porn_terms` below checks to see if a variable contains terms that are not family friendly, and it it does, then re-directs the user back to the main page.

As listed below, it checks to see if the variable `$title` has non-family friendly terms.  I would like to perform this check on another variable, `$cleanurl`.  Could I just replace `check_porn_terms($title)` below with `check_porn_terms($title, $cleanurl)` or something like that?  If not, how should I do it?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
if(!check_porn_terms($title))
{

   session_write_close();
   header("Location:http://www.domain.com/index.php");
   exit;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the function twice (combined with the "or" `||` operator) to check each variable:

```
if(!check_porn_terms($title) || !check_porn_terms($cleanurl))
{
    session_write_close();
    header("Location:http://www.domain.com/index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote the function yourself, redefine it to `check_porn_terms()` (no args), and then inside the function, loop over [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and check if each of the arguments are "clean".

But yes, you could have it take two arguments instead, if you wanted to. My point is, why stop at two? Let it take any number of arguments.

While you're at it, you could try actually reading the page, and scan the entire body of the page for dirty words.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to pass in additional parameters to `check_porn_terms`, you'd need to redefine the function

```
 function check_porn_terms($first_term, $second_term)
 {
     //code to check both terms here
 }
```

You could also rewrite the function to accept an array for parameters and then `foreach` over them, or get really fancy with func_get_args()

What you probably want to do, and can do without redefining the function, is to call the function twice

```
// the || means "or"
if(!check_porn_terms($title) || !check_porn_terms($cleanurl))
{
}
```